# FK without using moveit service

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a better way to determine forward kinematics for a given joint pose without having to go through MoveIt's FK service? I'm finding I need to call the FK service faster than it's compute time (around 20 ms for me).

I don't think using `tf2` is an option, as it will give me the current robot joint state. What I'm looking for is, essentially, a way to use the URDF/robot model to make a fk call with joint angles of my choosing, similar to how it can be done with the moveit service. I found [this](https://ros-planning.github.io/moveit_tutorials/doc/robot_model_and_robot_state/robot_model_and_robot_state_tutorial.html) on the moveit tutorials, which on the surface looks like I'd need to create a "dummy" robot kinematic state and update it's state with my desired joint angles, and then call the `getGlobalLinkTransform` as indicated. I looked around the moveit repo, and couldn't find where this service even originates. When I load up moveit, a `rosservice info /compute_fk` says it's launched by `move_group` but I couldn't find anywhere in there that showed how this was called.

Any thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372188/fk-without-using-moveit-service/) by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 261 on 2021-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, just use a `RobotModel` or `RobotState` in C++ as described in the tutorial. Your copy will not be updated to the "current"/"real" robot state, and you can define its state freely. You can copy most of the code from the `compute_fk` service, as you assumed.

The `compute_fk` service is a `move_group_capability` (a plugin that is started up by the `move_group` node) that is defined [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/b7711c134a8a1e173c9bf956f68ad8bbe27796c4/moveit_ros/move_group/src/default_capabilities/kinematics_service_capability.cpp#L175). The `move_group`'s plugin-based structure is a bit confusing to read, but [this explanation](https://moveit.ros.org/documentation/concepts/) should help.

I hope that solved what you were getting at.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emielke](https://answers.ros.org/users/27456/emielke/) on 2021-02-19**:
Yes thank you both for the help, this is what I was looking for!